# Python - Project Euler #57, understanding the error

Tags: python, iteration

When I run this code to calculate convergents of the root 2 continued fraction:

```
def root_two_expansion():
    total=0
    a=(3,2)
    b=(7,5)
    x=3
    while x<=1000:
        c=((sum(a)+sum(b)),sum(b))
        if len(str(c[0]))>len(str(c[1])):
            total+=1
        a=b,b=c
        x+=1
    return total

print root_two_expansion()
```

I receive this error:

> 069.506.py", line 7, in root_two_expansion
>       c=((sum(a)+sum(b)),sum(b))
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Why is this? I don't understand at which stage the code tries to iterate over an int. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: In future you should use a debugger e.g. in PyCharm to help you figure this kind of thing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
a=b,b=c
```

unpacks the tuple `c` in `b` and `b`, so only the second int is saved in `b`. In the next loop step you try to call `sum` on this int.

Did you mean

```
a, b = b, c
```

Comment: Of course, thank you. I am a complete programming noob so this is v helpful